# How can I handle an event to open a window in react js?

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, modal-dialog

I want to open a window after clicking the fshare:

My `render()` return is like this

```
<Modal.Footer>
    <img src="/static/img/fshare.png" onClick={this.fbShare} />
    <Button onClick={this.hide}>Close</Button>
</Modal.Footer>
```

I am creating a function

```
fbShare: function(event) {

},
```

And I want to add the following code inside the function that basically opens a new window to share in Facebook:

```
window.open('https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=xxxxxxxxe='sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');" target="_parent" href="javascript: void(0)">
```

But I am confused with how to handle this event.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You are on the right way!

Is it something you need? I prepared the example: 
click [here](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/25653/)

```
var Example = React.createClass({
    fbShare: function() {
        window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=Fb Share&p[summary]=Facebook share popup&p[url]=javascript:fbShare("http://jsfiddle.net/stichoza/EYxTJ/")&p[images][0]="http://goo.gl/dS52U"', 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');
    },

    render: function() {
        return (<div>
            <img src="http://pasadenainstitute.com/fb-shareTransp122x42.png" onClick={this.fbShare} />
        </div>);
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Example />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: I was unsure if it was correct to use the window.open code inside the function . Yes it works well thank you. However i ran into another problem, The Facebook dialogue box says This dialog has been passed a bad parameter [Click]https://jsfiddle.net/sidzan/0oycvn54/)

If i use normal javascript directly inline in the anchorl tag, the code runs and no errors are shown in the facebook dialogue box