# how to open a website in a new tab without allowing pop-up in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i got a scenario needs to open a page in new window based on user action
here my code

```
  openInWindow =(data)=>{
      var event = document.createElement('a');
      event.setAttribute('href',`https://www.valueresearchonline.com/funds/newsnapshot.asp?schemecode=${data.code}`);
      event.setAttribute('target','_blank');
      event.click();
  }
```

i am calling this method after an action

> please note i must send a code to that website

i am getting **pop-up blocked** in chrome and its asking for enable the pop-up for the browser

i tried this also but no use

```
window.open(`https://www.valueresearchonline.com/funds/newsnapshot.asp?schemecode=${data.code}`,'_blank');
```

is there any way in react to open a website in new tab without allowing the pop-up in browser

Comment: you don't have to do anything react specific, you need to call your handler function where `window.open` is executed. Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open or follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34507160/how-can-i-handle-an-event-to-open-a-window-in-react-js

Comment: i went trough those link and tried  but if user blocks the pop-up then it's not working

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this? :

1. create a unique identifier
2. open blank new window
3. in new window component use an ajax call and pass your identifier
4. get whatever you need form server
5. load data in componentdidMount in the new window

Comment: first 4 steps are fine., how we could load data in componentdidMount of page which we don't have  any control

Comment: on your first page, you have to pass some critical data to your server and get a unique identifier from that page (server keep that data) you open new windows and pass your identifier as a prop to your new component and in componentDidMount use that identifier to get your data from server componentDidmount(){const {identifier} = this props $.post("url",data).done(response => {set your data})}